# Given the local relative url to an image, how can I get actual image to send

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am writing an express app where one endpoint takes in an image and I would then send that image to a third-party Api. I used `multer` to save the image to disk, and I have the relative file path to the image, but the API I am trying to call needs the actual image or an image url. The problem is that i'm passing just a string value that contains the filepath to the image. Here is what I have currently:

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

And I need to call the image in this api call here:

```
router.post('/images/tags/info/image', upload.single('fileName'), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file.path);
    var imageUrl = req.file.path;
    app.models.predict('APP_KEY', imageUrl).then(
        function (response) {
            var responseJson = JSON.stringify(response.data.outputs[0].data.concepts);
            var data = collectTags(responseJson);
            data.then(function(value) {
                res.json(value);
            });
        },
        function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

When I `console.log(req.file.filePath)`, I get a valid filepath, but I need the actual image to pass into the `app.models.predict(API_KEY, image)`

Comment: What happens when you remove the `.path` and just send `req.file`

Comment: I get a 400 error with `badrequest`

Comment: `data:
   { status:
      { code: 11100,
        description: 'Bad request format',
        details: 'Invalid json path \'inputs[0].data.image.destination\' in request.' } } }`

Comment: What does the `predict ` function do?

Comment: It takes in an image and generates a list of tags on that image. It also takes in imageURLS

Answer (score 1):

You can just read the image from the file system and send it to the api. 
e.g.

```
      const bitmap = await q.nfcall(fs.readFile,req.file.path);
      //remove the temp image
      fs.unlink(req.file.path);        
      const buffer = new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
      app.models.predict('APP_KEY', buffer);
```

Example sending the image as base64 (using async/await).

Comment: `const bitmap = await q.nfcall(fs.readFile,req.file.path);`, it says q is an unexpected identifier!

Comment: I'm using q promise, for promisify, but you can just replace by your own like bluebird or es6 promises. It's just to work with async code.

Comment: Could you write the full solution? i'm having some issues with the `q.nfcall` part